# Two domain & their sub-domain are mapped to the same IP so how can i host my different application to the same tomcat server?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, tomcat, jakarta-ee, virtualhost

I have two different domain & sub domain.

For example :-

`Domain 1 :- example1.com   IP :- XXX.XX.XX.201
Domain 2 :- example2.com   IP :- XXX.XX.XX.202 (This is a virtual hosting on above IP addr XXX.XX.XX.201)`

I am also using sub-domains for the same like,

`Domain 1 :- test.example1.com   IP :- XXX.XX.XX.201
Domain 2 :- test.example2.com   IP :- XXX.XX.XX.202 (This is a virtual hosting on above IP addr XXX.XX.XX.201)`

I have to access the application in such way that if i access example.com it will redirect to me app1 and test.example.com will redirect mi to app2.

I have done some configuration related to this in my server.xml of tomcat.

`<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"></Host>`

`<Host name="example2.com" appBase="webapps_example2">
    <Alias>test.example2.com</Alias>
</Host>`

If i hit URL like,

`1.` http://example2.com   -> I want to show an application `app1`

`2.` http://test.example2.com   -> I want to show an application `app2`

I have deployed app1 in webapps_example2 & when i hit any of the above URL .. both the URL redirecting to the same `app1`. Where should i deploy my `app2` so it will be accessible by above url no 2.

**Note** :- `test.example.com is a just sample url & sub-domains may be change anytime so i can't put separate virtual host for entry & webapps folder for each sub domain.
app1 is simple html website & app2 is an J2EE application`

Can anyone help me for doing this ???

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Connector port="80" ... />
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  <Host name="example.com" appBase="webapps-example"></Host>

  <Host name="test.example.com" appBase="webapps-test.example"></Host>
</Engine>
```

Now, move `app1` to `webapps-example/ROOT` (case matters) (you ought to have webapps-example/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml`for example) and move`app2`to`webapps-test.example/ROOT`.

That ought to do it for `example.com`. You can do the same for `example2.com`, etc.

If you want a hostname to map to a single web application, you *must* name the web application `ROOT` and put it into its own "webapps" (`appBase`) directory. You will have to duplicate the `<Host>` configuration for every virtual host you want to support.

If you are more relaxed about your requirements, you can do things in a more flexible way without having to define all those `<Host>` elements.

Comment: **Thanks Christopher**, Its working fine with your solution & its full-filling my requirements about accessing application with specific URL.